# Using sql function generate_series() in redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, generate-series

I'd like to use the generate series function in redshift, but have not been successful.

The redshift documentation says it's not supported. The following code does work:

```
select *
from generate_series(1,10,1)
```

outputs:

```
1
2
3
...
10
```

I'd like to do the same with dates. I've tried a number of variations, including:

```
select *
from generate_series(date('2008-10-01'),date('2008-10-10 00:00:00'),1)
```

kicks out:

```
 ERROR: function generate_series(date, date, integer) does not exist
 Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types.
 You may need to add explicit type casts. [SQL State=42883]
```

Also tried:

```
select *
from generate_series('2008-10-01 00:00:00'::timestamp,
'2008-10-10 00:00:00'::timestamp,'1 day')
```

And tried:

```
select *
from generate_series(cast('2008-10-01 00:00:00' as datetime),
cast('2008-10-10 00:00:00' as datetime),'1 day')
```

both kick out:

```
ERROR: function generate_series(timestamp without time zone, timestamp without time zone, "unknown") does not exist
Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types.
You may need to add explicit type casts. [SQL State=42883]
```

If not looks like I'll use this code from another post:

```
SELECT to_char(DATE '2008-01-01'
+ (interval '1 month' * generate_series(0,57)), 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS ym
```

[PostgreSQL generate_series() with SQL function as arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7955407/postgresql-generate-series-with-sql-function-as-arguments)

Comment: Run `SELECT version()` against your database to retrieve your version of Postgres.

Comment: For a workaround see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34167753/3019685

Comment: I have posted a workaround in a similar question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22759980/generate-series-method-fails-in-redshift

Answer (score 26):

Amazon [Redshift seems to be based on PostgreSQL 8.0.2](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_redshift-and-postgres-sql.html). The timestamp arguments to generate_series() were added in 8.4.

Something like this, which sidesteps that problem, *might* work in Redshift.

```
SELECT current_date + (n || ' days')::interval
from generate_series (1, 30) n
```

It works in PostgreSQL 8.3, which is the earliest version I can test. It's documented in 8.0.26.

**Later . . .**

It seems that [generate_series() is unsupported](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_unsupported-postgresql-functions.html) in Redshift. But given that you've verified that `select * from generate_series(1,10,1)` *does* work, the syntax above at least gives you a fighting chance. (Although the interval data type is also documented as being unsupported on Redshift.)

**Still later . . .**

You could also create a table of integers.

```
create table integers (
  n integer primary key
);
```

Populate it however you like. You might be able to use generate_series() locally, dump the table, and load it on Redshift. (I don't know; I don't use Redshift.)

Anyway, you can do simple date arithmetic with that table without referring directly to generate_series() or to interval data types.

```
select (current_date + n)
from integers
where n < 31;
```

That works in 8.3, at least.

Answer (score 21):

Using Redshift today, you can generate a range of dates by using datetime functions and feeding in a number table.

```
select (getdate()::date - generate_series)::date from generate_series(1,30,1)
```

Generates this for me

```
date
2015-11-06
2015-11-05
2015-11-04
2015-11-03
2015-11-02
2015-11-01
2015-10-31
2015-10-30
2015-10-29
2015-10-28
2015-10-27
2015-10-26
2015-10-25
2015-10-24
2015-10-23
2015-10-22
2015-10-21
2015-10-20
2015-10-19
2015-10-18
2015-10-17
2015-10-16
2015-10-15
2015-10-14
2015-10-13
2015-10-12
2015-10-11
2015-10-10
2015-10-09
2015-10-08
```

Comment: while this generates a series, I have found no way (CTE, subquery, or inserting into a table or temporary table to join it to another table for filtering).

Comment: @cfeduke you could wrap this into a temp table as ```with series AS (
select * from generate_series(1,10,1)
)
select * from series```

Comment: @blotto - thank you!  Your comment and the last example in the question solved the problem for me.

Comment: The query, `with series AS ( select * from generate_series(1,10,1) ) select * from series`, does work. However, as soon as join it with another table, `with series AS ( select * from generate_series(1,10,1) ) select * from series join mytable on true`, then I still get the error `Function "generate_series(integer,integer,integer)" not supported.`

Comment: I'm having the same result as @SlobodanPejic: bizarrely:

-this works perfectly to generate a date range CTE, 
-and I can run that code in Redshift and get the expected date range, 
-but if I try to join onto that date range elsewhere, I get  `Function "generate_series(bigint,bigint)" not supported.`

Answer (score 13):

The `generate_series()` function is not fully supported by Redshift. See the [**Unsupported PostgreSQL functions**](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_unsupported-postgresql-functions.html) section of the developer guide.

**UPDATE**

generate_series is working with Redshift now.

```
SELECT CURRENT_DATE::TIMESTAMP  - (i * interval '1 day') as date_datetime 
FROM generate_series(1,31) i 
ORDER BY 1
```

This will generate last 30 days date

Ref: [generate_series function in Amazon Redshift](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22554398/1939568)

Comment: It appears that `generate_series()` works occasionally, but reliably fails if and when used in queries joining to actual tables. My guess is that these example queries are running on the leader node and succeeding, but fail when running on other nodes. From your link to the unsupported functions docs: "some unsupported functions will not return an error when run on the leader node"

Answer (score 4):

As of writing this, `generate_series()` on our instance of Redshift (1.0.33426) could not be used to, for example, create a table:

```sql
# select generate_series(1,100,1);
1
2
...

# create table normal_series as select generate_series(1,100,1);
INFO: Function "generate_series(integer, integer, integer) not supported.
ERROR: Specified types or functions (one per INFO message) not supported on Redshift tables.
```

However, `with recursive` works:

```sql
# create table recursive_series as with recursive t(n) as (select 1::integer union all select n+1 from t where n < 100) select n from t;
SELECT

-- modify as desired, here is a date series:
# select getdate()::date + n from recursive_series;
2021-12-18
2021-12-19
...
```

Comment: This is a really nice answer - for reference, recursive CTE's are supported in Redshift since about a year ago: https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2021/04/amazon-redshift-announces-support-for-hierarchical-data-queries-with-recursive-cte/

Answer (score 2):

I needed to do something similar, but with 5 minutes intervals over 7 days. So here's a CTE based hack (ugly but not too verbose)

```
INSERT INTO five_min_periods
WITH 
periods  AS (select 0 as num UNION select 1 as num UNION select 2 UNION select 3 UNION select 4 UNION select 5 UNION select 6 UNION select 7 UNION select 8 UNION select 9 UNION select 10 UNION select 11),
hours    AS (select num from periods UNION ALL select num + 12 from periods),
days     AS (select num from periods where num <= 6),
rightnow AS (select CAST( TO_CHAR(GETDATE(), 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24') || ':' || trim(TO_CHAR((ROUND((DATEPART (MINUTE, GETDATE()) / 5), 1) * 5 ),'09')) AS TIMESTAMP) as start)
select  
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY d.num DESC, h.num DESC, p.num DESC) as idx
  , DATEADD(minutes, -p.num * 5, DATEADD( hours, -h.num, DATEADD( days, -d.num, n.start ) ) ) AS period_date
from days d, hours h, periods p, rightnow n
```

Should be able to extend this to other generation schemes. The trick here is using the Cartesian product join (i.e. no JOIN/WHERE clause) to multiply the hand-crafted CTE's to produce the necessary increments and apply to an anchor date.

Answer (score 2):

Redshift's generate_series() function is a leader node only function and as such you cannot use it for downstream processing on the compute nodes.  This can be replace by a recursive CTE (or keep a "dates" table on your database).  I have an example of such in a recent answer:

[Cross join Redshift with sequence of dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70290670/cross-join-redshift-with-sequence-of-dates/70297632#70297632)

One caution I like to give in answers like this is to be careful with inequality joins (or cross joins or any under-qualified joins) when working with VERY LARGE tables which can happen often in Redshift.  If you are joining with a moderate Redshift table of say 1M rows then things will be fine.  But if you are doing this on a table of 1B rows then the data explosion will likely cause massive performance issues as the query spills to disk.

I've written a couple of white papers on how to write this type of query in a data space sensitive way.  This issue of massive intermediate results is not unique to Redshift and I first developed my approach solving a client's HIVE query issue.  "First rule of writing SQL for Big Data - don't make more"

Answer (score 0):

Per the comments of [@Ryan Tuck](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22782384/1450420) and [@Slobodan Pejic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33577864/1450420) `generate_series()` does not work on Redshift when joining to another table.

The workaround I used was to write out every value in the series in the query:

```sql
SELECT
'2019-01-01'::date AS date_month
UNION ALL
SELECT
'2019-02-01'::date AS date_month
```

Using a Python function like this:

```python
import arrow

def generate_date_series(start, end):
    start = arrow.get(start)
    end = arrow.get(end)

    months = list(
        f"SELECT '{month.format('YYYY-MM-DD')}'::date AS date_month"
        for month in arrow.Arrow.range('month', start, end)
    )

    return "\nUNION ALL\n".join(months)
```

Answer (score 0):

perhaps not as elegant as other solutions, but here's how I did it:

```
drop table if exists #dates;
create temporary table #dates as
with recursive cte(val_date) as
    (select 
        cast('2020-07-01' as date) as val_date
    union all
    select
        cast(dateadd(day, 1, val_date) as date) as val_date
    from 
        cte
    where 
        val_date <= getdate()
    )
select 
    val_date as yyyymmdd
from
    cte
order by
    val_date
;
```

Answer (score 0):

For five minute buckets i would do the following:

```
select date_trunc('minute', getdate()) - (i || ' minutes')::interval
from generate_series(0, 60*5-1, 5) as i
```

You could replace 5 by any given interval, and 60 by the number of rows you want.

Answer (score 0):

an anti-best practice solution, but useful for ad hoc data generation tasks.
You can use some existing table and get row_number()

select row_number() over() as i
from some_table
limit 10

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT CURRENT_DATE::TIMESTAMP - (i * interval '1 day') as date_datetime 
FROM generate_series(1,(select datediff(day,'01-Jan-2021',now()::date))) i 
ORDER BY 1
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).