# SQL (RedShift): Select distinct dates for each month from a column of timestamps

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-redshift

I have a column of timestamps:

```
time_column
2016-02-02 08:09:59.351000
2016-02-02 15:09:21.756000
2016-02-02 15:42:33.287000
2016-02-02 15:53:26.394000
```

I would like to write a query that outputs distinct timestamps for a given month.

So, the output would be

```
jan    feb    mar    apr    may    jun     ....
 9      1      10    ...
```

Is this possible to do in sql, or do I need to run the query for each month separately (by doing something like counting distinct `date_trunc(...)` for each month)?

EDIT:

Based on advice to look at pivot tables, I attempted to construct a solution as follows (however I believe there may be an issue with Redshift accepting crosstab). I'm hoping the real issue is my query and not redshift.

```
SELECT * FROM crosstab(
$$SELECT
    column1,
    column2,
    date_part('Month', my_timestamp) as month,
    count(date_trunc('Month',my_timestamp))
FROM my_table
GROUP BY column1, column2, month$$,

$$SELECT m FROM generate_series(1,6) m$$
) AS (
              column1 CHARACTER VARYING,
              column2 CHARACTER VARYING,
              "Jan" INT,
              "Feb" INT,
              "Mar" INT,
              "Apr" INT,
              "May" INT,
              "Jun" INT
)
```

Throws the error:

> [42883] ERROR: function crosstab("unknown", "unknown") does not exist
>     Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You may need to add explicit type casts.

Comment: Yes it is. It is called Pivoting Table. Search for it here, there are thousands of examples. Try something and then, if you can't do it, show us what you tried so we will gladly help you.

Comment: @JorgeCampos Thanks. The terminology helped.

Comment: @JorgeCampos edited added. Not sure what the issue is. Perhaps a redshift peculiarity?

Comment: Add the error message you are getting.

Comment: @JorgeCampos updated.

Comment: Well it seems that redshift doesn't support crosstab, just add it as two tables the effect is the same like `select * from (subselect 1) as t1, (subselect 2) as t2`

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Redshift does not support pivot operations (i.e crosstab).

You can either

1. Do what Jorge suggests in the comments and manually select the necessary data
2. If that data is small enough, output into a program that can handle pivots.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a sum of case statement for each month

```
select 
sum(case when extract('month' from time_column) = 1 then 1 else 0 end) Jan,
sum(case when extract('month' from time_column) = 2 then 1 else 0 end) Feb,
....
from table_name
```

Answer (score 0):

Redshift doesn't fully support `generate_series()` either (See https://stackoverflow.com/a/34167753/3019685).

This will give you the data you want but not formatted into one row:

```
select to_char(time_column, 'mon') as month, count(*) from your_table group by 1

 month | count
-------+-------
 jun   |   166
 feb   |     1
 mar   |    59
 may   |   198
 apr   |   231
```

Comment: The question asks for _distinct_ timestamps, so I would alter this query a bit: `select to_char(time_column, 'mon') as month, count(DISTINCT time_column) from your_table group by 1`