# Need assistance creating multiple rows for every month between two dates in one row

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I am trying to create a dashboard which shows monthly revenue for every month. I think the best way to do this would be to create a table that has a row for every month with the revenue next to it. One row of data currently looks like this:

```
Subscription_ID|    Start_Date| End_Date    |Monthly_revenue
2384105        |    1/1/2016  | 6/1/2016    |500
```

I would want to somehow transform that line to look like the following lines:

```
Subscription_ID |Month    |Monthly_Revenue
2384105         |1/1/2016 | 500
2384105         |2/1/2016 | 500
2384105         |3/1/2016 | 500
2384105         |4/1/2016 | 500
2384105         |5/1/2016 | 500
2384105         |6/1/2016 | 500
```

I have no idea how to even go about this.  Any advice would be greatly appreciated or if you can point me in the right direction. I'm using redshift as my DB so the syntax is mostly similar to postgres.

Edit: Reply to comment - I can easily make a table with all dates and years in it if that would help to reference.

Comment: Redshift doesn't support recursive cte's to generate dates between any 2 given dates. Do you have a table with all months and years combination?

Comment: without a recursive cte you could still do it with a tally table

Comment: You would traditionally do this in PostgreSQL using `generate_series()` however RedShift is based on an older version that did not have it. This may have some alternative methods that could help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22759980/generate-series-in-redhsift/34167753#34167753

Comment: I replaced the sql-server version of my answer with a PostgreSQL version that should work because it is not using recursion or generate_series()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay I looked at some redshift documentation something like this should work:

DATEDIFF http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_DATEDIFF_function.html

Common Table Expressions http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_WITH_clause.html

DATEADD http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_DATEADD_function.html

```
WITH cteData AS (
    SELECT 
       CAST(2384105 AS INTEGER) AS Subscription_ID
       ,CAST('2016-01-01' AS DATE) AS Start_Date
       ,CAST('2016-06-01' AS DATE) AS End_Date
       ,CAST(500 AS INTEGER) AS Monthly_revenue
)

,cteTally AS (
        SELECT 0 AS TallyNum
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 1
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 2
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 3
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 4
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 5
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 6
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 7
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 8
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 9
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 10
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 11
    )


    SELECT
        Subscription_ID
       ,DATEADD(month,c.TallyNum,t.Start_date) AS "Month"
        ,Monthly_revenue
    FROM
        cteData t
        INNER JOIN cteTally c
        ON DATEDIFF(month,t.Start_Date,t.End_Date) >= c.TallyNum
```

this may work for you as it does not use generate_series() or recursive cte. this is postgresSQL version I tried this with SQL Fiddle (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/f3a23/7/0)....

```
CREATE TABLE Tbl (
  Subscription_ID INTEGER
  ,Start_Date DATE
  ,End_Date DATE
  ,Monthly_revenue INTEGER);

INSERT INTO Tbl (Subscription_ID, Start_Date, End_Date, Monthly_revenue)
VALUES (2384105,'2016-01-01','2016-06-01',500);

WITH cteTally AS (
    SELECT 0 AS TallyNum
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 3
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 4
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 5
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 6
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 7
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 8
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 9
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 10
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 11
)

SELECT
    Subscription_ID
    ,(t.Start_Date + (c.TallyNum * '1 month'::INTERVAL)) as "Month"
    ,Monthly_revenue
FROM
    Tbl t
    INNER JOIN cteTally c
    ON (
      (DATE_PART('year', t.End_Date) - DATE_PART('year', t.Start_Date)) * 12
      +
      (DATE_PART('month', t.End_Date) - DATE_PART('month', t.Start_Date))
    ) >= c.TallyNum
;
```

Comment: thanks for this. I am unfamiliar with these unctions however I don't think ctetally is supported in redshift. There is no documentation from them around these functions

Comment: according to this document cteTally which is a common table expression should work in redshift.  http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_WITH_clause.html  as far as the date time functions yeah that is postgressql version the ms sql-server is actually a lot simpler for the date operations.

Comment: AH! I'm so dumb I thought ctetally was a function not the table name! thanks I will try this.  Also keep in mind the area that you have VALUES() I have thousands of rows with different values so can I reference the column names?

Comment: yes you can reference column names.  I only used values to create example data to test with.  I just edited the answer though as it looks like you can actually use syntax more similar to sql-server rather than postgressql which will made the datetime calculations easier.  Anyway, both are up there give it a shot.

Comment: @Matt For me I am getting this error in redshift:
**SQL Error [500310] [XX000]: [Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: Interval values with month or year parts are not supported**