# Insert multiple rows from a single select

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I am using redshift postgres

I want the output to be a daily

Output Table monthly_user_activity

```
id  maudate     date       userid
1   2016-10-10  2016-10-10 MjA1MDATG2TDUwOTE2MD 
2   2016-10-11  2016-10-10 MjA1MDATG2TDUwOTE2MD
3   2016-10-12  2016-10-10 MjA1MDATG2TDUwOTE2MD
4   2016-10-13  2016-10-10 MjA1MDATG2TDUwOTE2MD
5   2016-10-14  2016-10-10 MjA1MDATG2TDUwOTE2MD
6   2016-10-15  2016-10-10 MjA1MDATG2TDUwOTE2MD
7   2016-10-16  2016-10-10 MjA1MDATG2TDUwOTE2MD
...
30   2016-11-09 2016-10-10 MjA1MDATG2TDUwOTE2MD
```

Input Table user_activity:

```
id  date        userid
1   2016-10-10  MjA1MDATG2TDUwOTE2MD
```

My input is just a single row that represents a users activity on a day, for each row in this table below I want to create 30 copies of days in the future, this is how I will calculate a daily MAU

I tried something like this, below but i would have to run this query 30 times and it seems not very DRY.

```
INSERT INTO monthly_user_activity 
( maudate, date, userid )
SELECT 
original_date::date + interval '0 day',
original_date,
userid
FROM (
SELECT
date as original_date,
userid
FROM
    user_activity
)

INSERT INTO monthly_user_activity 
( maudate, date, userid )
SELECT 
original_date::date + interval '1 day',
original_date,
userid
FROM (
SELECT
date as original_date,
userid
FROM
    user_activity
)

INSERT INTO monthly_user_activity 
( maudate, date, userid )
SELECT 
original_date::date + interval '2 day',
original_date,
userid
FROM (
SELECT
date as original_date,
userid
FROM
    user_activity
)

---...
INSERT INTO monthly_user_activity 
( maudate, date, userid )
SELECT 
original_date::date + interval '30 day',
original_date,
userid
FROM (
SELECT
date as original_date,
userid
FROM
    user_activity
)
```

**update from comments**
Is this the right way using that link you sent me.

```
SELECT
id
d::date,
date as original_date,
userid
FROM user_activity,
(
select (dateadd(day, +row_number() over (order by true), date)) as d
    from user_activity limit 30
)
```

Comment: Redshift does not support generate_series in a useful way. There are workarounds: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34167753/3019685.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After `PostgreSQL 8.4`:

With `generate_series(start, stop, step interval)` you can populate dates for your monthly insert data:

```
SELECT
t.d::date,
date as original_date,
user_id
FROM user_activity,
generate_series(date,date+ interval '1 month - 1 day','1 day') t(d)
```

look at this link for more information [generate_series](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-srf.html)

before `PostgreSQL 8.4` you can create your own function:

```
create or replace function generate_series_date(begin_date integer,end_date integer)
RETURNS integer AS $$

declare

affected_rows integer :=0;
integer_var integer:=0;

begin
 FOR i IN begin_date..end_date LOOP
  INSERT INTO monthly_user_activity 
     ( mau_date, date, user_id )
  select
  date+ "interval"(''''||i||' day'''),
  date,
  user_id
  FROM user_activity;

  GET DIAGNOSTICS integer_var  = ROW_COUNT;
  affected_rows = affected_rows+integer_var;

  END LOOP;

  return affected_rows;

  end;
$$  LANGUAGE plpgsql
```

Comment: i am getting function generate_series(timestamp without time zone, timestamp without time zone, "unknown") does not exist;

Comment: What is your PostgreSQL version?

Comment: PostgreSQL 8.0.2 on i686-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by GCC gcc (GCC) 3.4.2 20041017 (Red Hat 3.4.2-6.fc3), Redshift 1.0.1231

Comment: Thank you for your update light souls! I got  Invalid operation: Create Function is not supported for language plpgsql  I tried systemjacks work around and i am getting a little bit further

Comment: You are not using PostgreSQL. you are using amazon redshift. This link might help you. [dateadd](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_DATEADD_function.html)