# Is there a way to generate a series using results of queries in Redshift?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I want to use the max of some value in a table as the max of a generated series in order to get a table without holes. I tried

```
SELECT n
FROM (SELECT MAX(amount) as max FROM my_table) h, 
generate_series(1,h.max,1) n
```

and also

```
SELECT *
FROM generate_series(1,10,1) n
RIGHT JOIN  (SELECT MAX(amount) AS max FROM my_table) h ON h.max > n
```

which generates following error

`java.lang.RuntimeException: com.amazon.support.exceptions.ErrorException: [Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: Specified types or functions (one per INFO message) not supported on Redshift tables.;`

I tried preparing the max in a with close, I tried preparing the generate_series in a with close but nothing was working. I always get this same kind of error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the discussion on 
[generate_series() method fails in Redshift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22759980/generate-series-method-fails-in-redshift)
I found a solution for my specific problem. I first create a range which is big enough (this might be problematic in the future and any better solution is very wellcome). And then I join this range with my max value on where the ranges values are smaller than my max value.

```
with
 range as (
    select (row_number() over (order by true)) as num
    from [some_big_enough_table] limit 30
)
SELECT num FROM range INNER JOIN (SELECT MAX(amount) m FROM my_table) h
WHERE num <= m
```

Answer (score 1):

Because I'm quoting the documentation, this is too long for a comment.

Amazon Redshift does not support [`generate_series()`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_unsupported-postgresql-functions.html):

> These PostgreSQL functions are not supported in Amazon Redshift.
>
> Set returning functions
>
> - GENERATE_SERIES()
> - GENERATE_SUBSCRIPTS()

This makes your problem harder to solve in Redshift than you might expect.  I would suggest that you ask another question, with more details about how you want to use the data.  For instance:

- Are you just looking for gaps?
- Is the table pretty dense -- meaning that there are relatively few gaps compared to the number of values?
- Do you have another "tally" table that has enough rows to generate the values?

Comment: How comes then that `SELECT * FROM  generate_series(1,10,1)` yields the expected results?

Comment: @YannickSSE . . . I cannot answer the question of why a function that is documented not to work (and did not used to work when I tried it myself) would actually work on a system.  The function definitely works in Postgres, though.

Comment: @YannickSSE it's because this function when executed separately is running on a leader node. Everything that involves data runs on compute nodes which doesn't support it.

Comment: @AlexYes . . . That would also be my assumption, but the documentation does not include it in leader-node functions:  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_SQL_functions_leader_node_only.html.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to come up with an arbitrarily limited range with what you have here? Something like this might work:

```
with range as (
    select num from (
        select row_number() over (order by true) as num
        from [large_table]
        limit 30 -- some reasonable upper limit
    ) where num < (select max(amount) m from my_table)+1
)
```

For zero based just subtract 1 from num: `select num-1 as num from`