# Optimization: How to get TimeId from time for each minute in a week?

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-optimization, amazon-redshift

I am creating a table which will have 2 columns:

1. Day_time (time from `1978-01-01 00:00:00` Sunday, till `1978-01-07 23:59:00.0` Saturday, Granularity: Minute)
2. Time_id (a unique id for each minute), to be populated

I have column one populated. I want to populate column two.

How I am doing it right now:

`EXTRACT(dayofweek FROM day_time) * 10000 + DATEDIFF('minutes', TRUNC(day_time), day_time)`

I basically want a function where I pass any date and it tells me where I am in a week. **So, I need a function, just like the function above. Just more optimized, where I give a date and get a unique ID. The unique ID should repeat weekly.**

> Example: ID for `Jan 1, 2015 00:00:00` will be same as `Jan 8, 2015 00:00:00`.

```
Why 1978-01-01? cuz it starts from a Sunday.    
Why 10,000? cuz the number of minutes in a day are in four digits.
```

Comment: @wingedpanther, thanks for the reply soldier. I am sorry, I was not clear. I want a function like the one I have written, as I want to calculate the same Id on the fly as well. I know recursive CTE's bro and I don't need a CTE to generate the Unique key, I can just Identity. Am I right, or am I right?

Comment: Does Amazon Redshift support *any* of these PostgreSQL features: CTEs, recursive CTEs, sequences, generate_series()?

Comment: Try this `insert into tbl 
select row_number() over() id,dtm
 from(
select generate_series('1978-01-01 00:00:00'::timestamp,'1978-01-02 23:59:00.0'::timestamp,'1min'::interval) dtm
)t`... Initially I just misunderstood your req.

Comment: Error: `function generate_series(timestamp without time zone, timestamp without time zone, interval) does not exist;` but `generate_series(1,30)` is working fine. I am new to this, can you see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17282276/using-sql-function-generate-series-in-redshift

Comment: [This](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/f2674/4) is it....

Comment: Anyways, how will I get the ID from the date on the fly using this? I think I won't be able to.

Comment: I've used `row_number() over()`, have you checked my fiddle??

Comment: May be http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22554398/generate-series-function-in-amazon-redshift could be a reason on your side

Comment: @wingedpanther I really appreciate your help. I have update the question, please see the highlighted part. Sorry for the confusion. Obviously I have seen the fiddle. I guess I was not able to explain question properly. There we are generating the ids, I am saying I can do that using Identity column as well, right? I want a function.

Comment: @DeepanshuKalra Still I cannot understand your requirement well. IMO sample DDL,data and expected output would be much helpful

Comment: @wingedpanther need a function, just like the function I have above. just more optimized, where I give a date and get a unique ID. The unique ID should repeat weekly. Which means: ID for `Jan 1, 2015 00:00:00` will be same as `Jan 8, 2015 00:00:00`.

Comment: a) If it repeats, it's not unique. b) The trunc() function takes a number, not a timestamp. Does your expression *really* work on Redshift?

Comment: Are you trying to calculate the number of minutes since midnight the previous Sunday?

Comment: @MikeSherrill'CatRecall' Yes my expression works and I am using it from more than a month now. And I want it to repeat, but after a week, it should be unique for a week.

Comment: What is wrong with the current function ? As you say, it works. If performance is an issue you might consider pre-calculating the values and storing them in a separate table and then `JOIN`-ing against that table to find the required `ID`. If your source-data already is "rounded" to the minute, then this would work very well (the datetime field should be the PK), otherwise you'll need to do the "rounding" inside the `JOIN` predicate and that's going to kill performance even more than the function you're already using I fear.

Comment: PS: You could try adding a start/end column approach in the pre-calculated table and then `JOIN` with `BETWEEN` but that's probably not very fast either...

Comment: I was not able to think of any approach faster than the one I mentioned in question. I have implemented the system using this. But will love to know how I can optimize it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it all in one fell swoop, without needing to extract the date separately:

`SELECT DATEDIFF('minutes', date_trunc('week',day_time), day_time)` which I'd expect to be marginally faster.

Another approach that I'd expect to be significantly faster would be converting the timestamp to epoch, dividing by 60 to get minutes from epoch and then taking the value modulus of 10,080 (for 60 * 24 * 7 minutes in a week).

`SELECT (extract(epoch from day_time) / 60) % 10080`

If you don't care about the size of the weekly index, you could also do:

`SELECT (extract(epoch from day_time)) % 604800` and skip the division step altogether, which should make it faster still.