# Undo a LISTAGG in redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have a table that probably resulted from a listagg,  similar to this:

```
# select * from s;
     s     
-----------
 a,c,b,d,a
 b,e,c,d,f
(2 rows)
```

How can I change it into this set of rows:

```
a
c
b
d
a
b
e
c
d
f
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25112389/redshift-convert-comma-delimited-values-into-rows/31998832#31998832

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In redshift, you can join against a  table of numbers, and use that as the split index:

```
--with recursive Numbers as (
--  select 1 as i
--  union all
--  select i + 1 as i from Numbers where i <= 5
--)
with Numbers(i) as (
  select 1 union
  select 2 union
  select 3 union
  select 4 union
  select 5 
)
select split_part(s,',', i) from Numbers, s ORDER by s,i;
```

EDIT: redshift doesn't seem to support recursive subqueries, only postgres. :(

Comment: Redshift doesn't seem to support recursive subqueries

Answer (score 0):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b61675/5)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
create table s(
  col varchar2(20) );

insert into s values('a,c,b,d,a');
insert into s values('b,e,c,d,f');
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT  REGEXP_SUBSTR(t1.col, '([^,])+', 1, t2.COLUMN_VALUE )
FROM s t1 CROSS JOIN
TABLE
(
  CAST
  (
    MULTISET
    (
      SELECT LEVEL
      FROM DUAL 
      CONNECT BY LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT(t1.col, '([^,])+')
    )
    AS SYS.odciNumberList
 )
) t2
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b61675/5/0)**:

```
| REGEXP_SUBSTR(T1.COL,'([^,])+',1,T2.COLUMN_VALUE) |
|---------------------------------------------------|
|                                                 a |
|                                                 c |
|                                                 b |
|                                                 d |
|                                                 a |
|                                                 b |
|                                                 e |
|                                                 c |
|                                                 d |
|                                                 f |
```

Answer (score 0):

As this is tagged to Redshift and no answer so far has a complete overview from undoing a LISTAGG in Redshift properly, here is the code that solves all its use cases:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE s (
  s varchar(255) 
);

INSERT INTO s VALUES('a,c,b,d,a');
INSERT INTO s VALUES('b,e,c,d,f');

SELECT 
      TRIM(split_part(s.s,',',R::smallint)) AS s 
FROM s
LEFT JOIN (
SELECT 
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY 1) AS R
   FROM any_large_table
   LIMIT 1000
) extend_number 
ON (SELECT MAX(regexp_count(s.s,',')+1) FROM s) >= extend_number.R 
AND NULLIF(TRIM(split_part(s.s,',',extend_number.R::smallint)),'') IS NOT NULL;

DROP TABLE s;
```

Where “any_large_table” is any table you have in redshift already that has enough records for your purposes depending on the number of elements the list of each record will contain (i.e. in the above case, I ensure it is up to one-thousand records). Unfortunately, generate_series function does not work properly in Redshift as far as I know and that is the only way.

Another point of advise is check if you can get the values before they already list_agg whenever possible. As you can see from the above code, it looks quite complex, and you save a lot of maintenance time on your code if you keep things simple (that is, whenever the opportunity is available).