# Convert T-SQL Cross Apply to Redshift

Tags: amazon-redshift, query-performance, cross-apply

I am converting the following T-SQL statement to Redshift. The purpose of the query is to convert a column in the table with a value containing a comma delimited string with up to 60 values into multiple rows with 1 value per row.

```
SELECT 
id_1
, id_2
, value
into dbo.myResultsTable
FROM myTable
CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT([comma_delimited_string], ',')
WHERE [comma_delimited_string] is not null;
```

In SQL this processes 10 million records in just under 1 hour which is fine for my purposes. Obviously a direct conversation to Redshift isn't possible due to Redshift not having a Cross Apply or String Split functionality so I built a solution using the process detailed here ([Redshift. Convert comma delimited values into rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25112389/redshift-convert-comma-delimited-values-into-rows)) which utilizes split_part() to split the comma delimited string into multiple columns. Then another query that unions everything to get the final output into a single column. But the typical run takes over 6 hours to process the same amount of data.

I wasn't expecting to run into this issue just knowing the power difference between the machines. The SQL Server I was using for the comparison test was a simple server with 12 processors and 32 GB of RAM while the Redshift server is based on the dc1.8xlarge nodes (I don't know the total count). The instance is shared with other teams but when I look at the performance information there are plenty of available resources.

I'm relatively new to Redshift so I'm still assuming I'm not understanding something. But I have no idea what am I missing. Are there things I need to check to make sure the data is loaded in an optimal way (I'm not an adim so my ability to check this is limited)? Are there other Redshift query options that are better than the example I found? I've searched for other methods and optimizations but unless I start looking into Cross Joins, something I'd like to avoid (Plus when I tried to talk to the DBA's running the Redshift cluster about this option their response was a flat "No, can't do that.") I'm not even sure where to go at this point so any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: This isn't an answer, but as a newcomer to Redshift note that it has a column-orientated MPP architecture that is totally different from the SQL Server you were using previously. The amount of resources your query receives when you run it is governed by the Redshift "queue" configuration and the memory and slot allocation of that queue. Depending on this configuration your query might only be allocated a small subset of the available resources e.g. 5%. You should have a conversation with your DBAs about how the queue is configured and whether there is a better queue to run your query on.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution that works for me.

You need to do a JOIN on a number table, for which you can take any table as long as it has more rows that the numbers you need. You need to make sure the numbers are int by forcing the type. Using the funcion regexp_count on the column to be split for the ON statement to count the number of fields (delimiter +1), will generate a table with a row per repetition.

Then you use the split_part function on the column, and use the number.num column to extract for each of the rows a different part of the text.

```
SELECT comma_delimited_string, numbers.num, REGEXP_COUNT(comma_delimited_string , ',')+1 AS nfields, SPLIT_PART(comma_delimited_string, ',', numbers.num) AS field
FROM mytable
JOIN 
(
select
    (row_number() over (order by 1))::int as num 
from
    mytable
limit 15 --max num of fields
) as numbers
ON numbers.num <= regexp_count(comma_delimited_string , ',') + 1
```