# Generate time series with date and hour and create table in Amazon Redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I'd like to generate a table of dates and hours in Amazon Redshift. The following query would work in Postgresql 9.1 and above but unfortunately we're limited to Amazon Redshift, which resulted in error: "function generate_series does not exist."  Your help in generating time series in 8.02 like the result table would be greatly appreciated.

```
SELECT * FROM generate_series('2008-03-01 00:00'::timestamp, 
                          '2008-03-04 12:00', '10 hours');
  generate_series   

generate_series   
    ---------------------
     2008-03-01 00:00:00
     2008-03-01 10:00:00
     2008-03-01 20:00:00
     2008-03-02 06:00:00
     2008-03-02 16:00:00
     2008-03-03 02:00:00
     2008-03-03 12:00:00
     2008-03-03 22:00:00
     2008-03-04 08:00:00
```

**Edit**:
I was able to generate the time series that I wanted with the following code but was unable to create them into a table in Redshift.  Error message was:

"Specified types or functions (one per INFO message) not supported on Redshift tables."

```
SELECT '2017-01-01 00:00:00'::timestamp + x * interval'1 hour' AS Date_Time
FROM generate_series(0, 1000 * 24) AS g(x)
```

Any ideas how this can be created into a table in Redshift? Thanks.

Comment: Don't develop new stuff with PostgreSQL 8.0

Comment: Please don't use this version!

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention we're using Amazon Redshift which does not support generate_series to create a table. PostgreSQL 8.0.2 on i686-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by GCC gcc (GCC) 3.4.2 20041017 (Red Hat 3.4.2-6.fc3), Redshift 1.0.3906.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using sql function generate\_series() in redshift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17282276/using-sql-function-generate-series-in-redshift)

Comment: http://www.silota.com/docs/recipes/redshift-sequential-generate-series-numbers-time.html

Answer (score 0):

A script like this might help you,

```
CREATE or REPLACE function gen_ser() returns integer
as 
$body$
declare
query varchar;
i integer := 0;
begin
loop 
exit when i >= 100;
i:=i+10;
query :='Insert into table select ''01-01-2018''::timestamptz + '''|| i ||' hours'' ::interval;';
execute query;
end loop;
return 1;
end;
$body$
language plpgsql;
```

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: Please do not use this version anymore!

---

Works for Postgres 8.4 (could not check 8.0 but it should work as well)

[demo: db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_8.4&fiddle=3282afae707f77748c034a3dc430eb4b)

```
SELECT start_date + gs * interval '10 hours'
FROM (
    SELECT '2008-03-01 00:00:00'::timestamp as start_date, generate_series(1,10, 1) as gs
) s
```

1. `generate_series` from 1 to 10 and join the result against your starting timestamp. The result is a table with two columns: One with the start at every row, one with the numbers from 1 to 10.
2. now you can multiply the generated number with your interval and add this to the start.

---

**Edit:** [The problem is discussed already](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17282276/using-sql-function-generate-series-in-redshift)

Comment: @LeoJones Does this work for you? `generate_series` should work for integer ranges (even if not for date ranges) IIRC.

Comment: Thanks, S-Man.  I got the query to work but could not create a table from it in Redshift (see Edit).

Comment: @LeoJones Please describe what you tried to create the table.

Comment: @LeoJones It would be better to create a second question on Stackoverflow since it is not allowed to ask different questions in one thread. Please upvote/accept this on if it solves your origin problem and post a new question (maybe referring to this one)