# How to unpivot a table in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot, dynamic-sql, unpivot

I am having difficulties writing a Postgres function, as I am not familiar with it. I have multiple tables to import into Postgres with this format:

```
id | 1960 | 1961 | 1962 | 1963 | ...
____________________________________
 1    23     45     87     99
 2    12     31    ...
```

which I need to convert into this format:

```
id | year | value
_________________
 1   1960    23
 1   1961    45
 1   1962    87
 ...
 2   1960    12
 2   1961    31
 ...
```

I would imagine the function too to read like this:

```
SELECT all-years FROM imported_table;
CREATE a new_table;
FROM min-year TO max-year LOOP
     EXECUTE "INSERT INTO new_table (id, year, value) VALUES (id, year, value)";
END LOOP;
```

However, I'm having real trouble writing the nitty-gritty details for this. Would be easier for me to do that in PHP, but I am convinced that it's cleaner to do it directly in a Postgres-function.

The years (start and end) vary from table to table. And sometimes, I can even have years only for every fifth year or so ...

Comment: Version? `select version();`

Comment: All columns `NOT NULL`? Also, column names starting with a digit are impossible without double-quoting.

Comment: Thanks so much for the suggestions! I am running version 9.2.6. Important question: Isn't there any way to read the year columns in a more automated way? For once, there are fifty years which I would need to type then by hand, and secondly, the start and end year can vary from table to table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A **completely dynamic** version requires dynamic SQL. Use a plpgsql function with `EXECUTE`:

For **Postgres 9.2 or older** (before `LATERAL` was implemented):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_unpivot_years92(_tbl regclass, VARIADIC _years int[])
  RETURNS TABLE(id int, year int, value int) AS
$func$
BEGIN
   RETURN QUERY EXECUTE '
   SELECT id
        , unnest($1) AS year
        , unnest(ARRAY["'|| array_to_string(_years, '","') || '"]) AS val
   FROM   ' || _tbl || '
   ORDER  BY 1, 2'
   USING _years;
END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

For **Postgres 9.3 or later** (with `LATERAL`):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_unpivot_years(_tbl regclass, VARIADIC _years int[])
  RETURNS TABLE(id int, year int, value int) AS
$func$
BEGIN
   RETURN QUERY EXECUTE (SELECT
     'SELECT t.id, u.year, u.val
      FROM  ' || _tbl || ' t
      LEFT   JOIN LATERAL (
         VALUES ' || string_agg(format('(%s, t.%I)', y, y), ', ')
     || ') u(year, val) ON true
      ORDER  BY 1, 2'
      FROM   unnest(_years) y
      );
END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

About `VARIADIC`:

- [Return rows matching elements of input array in plpgsql function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17978310/return-rows-matching-elements-of-input-array-in-plpgsql-function)

Call for arbitrary years:

```
SELECT * FROM f_unpivot_years('tbl', 1961, 1964, 1963);
```

Same, passing an actual array:

```
SELECT * FROM f_unpivot_years('tbl', VARIADIC '{1960,1961,1962,1963}'::int[]);
```

For a long list of sequential years:

```
SELECT * 
FROM f_unpivot_years('t', VARIADIC ARRAY(SELECT generate_series(1950,2014)));
```

For a long list with regular intervals (example for every 5 years):

```
SELECT *
FROM f_unpivot_years('t', VARIADIC ARRAY(SELECT generate_series(1950,2010,5)));
```

Output as requested.

The function takes:
*1.* A valid table name - double-quoted if it's otherwise illegal (like `'"CaMeL"'`). Using the object identifier type `regclass` to assert correctness and **defend against SQL injection**. You may want to schema-qualify the tale name to be unambiguous (like `'public."CaMeL"'`). More:

- [Table name as a PostgreSQL function parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10705616/table-name-as-a-postgresql-function-parameter/10711349#10711349)

*2.* **Any** list of numbers corresponding to (double-quoted) column names.
***Or*** an actual array, prefixed with the keyword `VARIADIC`.

The array of columns does not have to be sorted in any way, but table and columns must exist or an exception is raised.

Output is sorted by `id` and `year` (as `integer`). If you want years to be sorted according to the sort order of the input array, make it just `ORDER  BY 1`. Sort order according to array is not strictly guaranteed, but works in the current implementation. More about that:

- [PostgreSQL unnest() with element number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8760419/postgresql-unnest-with-element-number/8767450#8767450)

Also works for `NULL` values.

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/d5a96/1) for both with examples.

#### References:

- [Is there something like a zip() function in PostgreSQL that combines two arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12414750/is-there-something-like-a-zip-function-in-postgresql-that-combines-two-arrays/12414884#12414884)
- [Table name as a PostgreSQL function parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10705616/table-name-as-a-postgresql-function-parameter/10711349#10711349)
- [PostgreSQL generate_series() with SQL function as arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7955407/postgresql-generate-series-with-sql-function-as-arguments/7955877#7955877)

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. That looks great. However, although it runs correctly in the SQLFiddle, it creates an error warning in my database: "syntax error at or near "CREATE"". Not sure if I entered the fields correctly: NAME unpivot; RETURNS numeric; MODE inout; TYPE numeric... or what this is. Do you have any idea?

Comment: @luftikus143: `RETURNS numeric`? Why? What is this? Just copy / paste my code and it should work.

Comment: Ah, got it now. Sorry! Works perfectly! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 4):

`PostgreSQL 9.3` offers as neat [JSON functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-json.html) which can be used for such tasks without defining new functions or knowing a number of columns.

```
SELECT id, (k).key as year, (k).value as value FROM
  (SELECT j->>'id' as id, json_each_text(j) as k
    FROM (
       SELECT row_to_json(tbl) as j FROM tbl) 
    as q)
    as r
WHERE (k).key <> 'id';
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/1714b/13

Comment: This is briljant: I have "periods" which need to be unpivoted. For some customers  quarters (i.e. 4 periods), sometimes weeks (i.e. 52 or 53 weeks). And they need to go into 1 DWH. This will do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

Parallel unnesting might be easier

```
select
    id,
    unnest(array[1960, 1961, 1962]) as year,
    unnest(array["1960", "1961", "1962"]) as value
from (values
    (1,23,45,87), (2,12,31,53)
) s(id, "1960", "1961", "1962")
;
 id | year | value 
----+------+-------
  1 | 1960 |    23
  1 | 1961 |    45
  1 | 1962 |    87
  2 | 1960 |    12
  2 | 1961 |    31
  2 | 1962 |    53
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is a `union all`:

```
select id, 1960 as year, "1960" as value
from table t
union all
select id, '1960', "1961"
from table t
. . .;
```

A somewhat more sophisticated way would be:

```
select t.id, s.yr,
       (case when s.yr = 1960 then "1960"
             when s.yr = 1961 then "1961"
             . . .
        end) as value
from table t cross join
     generate_series(1960, 1980) s(yr);
```

You can put this into another table using `insert` or `create table as`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way that's based on the method at https://blog.sql-workbench.eu/post/dynamic-unpivot/ and [another answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25796299/1319998), but uses the [hstore extension](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/hstore.html)

```sql
SELECT
  id,
  r.key AS year,
  r.value AS value
FROM
  imported_table t
CROSS JOIN
  each(hstore(t.*)) AS r(key, value)
WHERE
  -- This chooses columns that look like years
  -- In other cases you might need a different condition
  r.key ~ '^[0-9]{4}$'
```

It has a few benefits over other solutions:

- By using hstore and not jsonb, it hopefully minimises issues with type conversions (although hstore does convert everything to text)
- The columns don't need to be hard coded or known in advance. Here, columns are chosen by a regex on the name, but you could use any SQL logic based on the name (or even the value)
- It doesn't require PL/pgSQL - it's all SQL