# Unnesting in PostgreSql

Tags: sql, postgresql, unpivot

I have a table that has 30 columns and it keeps growing. I cannot break it into multiple tables as it causes some visualization issues on Tableau. So the solution I was looking at was to create a new table. The old looks like

```
id | name | city| country| metric1 | metric2|.....|metric30  
------------------------------------------------------------
1  | dgshfsshd| Bost |United Stats|sjdhsjdsjdhjs|gdshduadjd|.......|hdhsjfhsjfsjf
2  | jsghfghfg| gert |United Stats|sjdhsjdsjdhjs|gdshduadjd|.......|hdhsjfhsjfsjf
.  
.  
.
```

The new table format should be something like not sure if it will work (I'm open to new ideas as well)

```
id | name | city| country | metric name | metric value  
1  |dgfdhh| sjdh|sghshdjd|metric1|sjdsjhfsfhsjfhsjf  
2  |jagdha| qewt|shgshfgs|metric2|hfjshfjhsjfshjsfh  
.  
.  
.
```

Let me know if you have any more questions. I am using postgres

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1128737/unpivot-and-postgresql

Comment: I'm not sure that this solution works, forgot to add that the metrics have interdependency that is value of metric 4 depends on metric 3 and so on Not always but sometime. How to I get around that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to unpivot a table in PostgreSQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25625342/how-to-unpivot-a-table-in-postgresql)

Comment: another key word to search for solutions is UNPIVOT, unfortunately it doesn't appear postgresql has a nice unpivot function like some other platforms.  So there are 2 main more obvious solutions, 1) union all with x# of selects 2) cross join to a tally table and large case statement.  but the link I tagged also has some dynamic and json solutions that might be of interest

Answer (score 0):

You can unnest an array of those columns and use `with ordinality` to get the index of the column in the array

```
select t.id, t..name, t.city, t.country, 
       concat('metric', m.idx) as metric_name, 
       m.val as metric_value
from the_table t
  cross join lateral unnest(array[metric1,metric2,.....,metric30) with ordinality as m(val,idx);
```