# Convert one row into multiple rows with fewer columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, unpivot, lateral

I'd like to convert single rows into multiple rows in PostgreSQL, where some of the columns are removed. Here's an example of the current output:

```
name | st | ot | dt |
-----|----|----|----|
Fred | 8  | 2  | 3  |
Jane | 8  | 1  | 0  |
Samm | 8  | 0  | 6  |  
Alex | 8  | 0  | 0  |
```

Using the following query:

```
SELECT
   name, st, ot, dt
FROM
   times;
```

And here's what I want:

```
name |  t | val |
-----|----|-----|
Fred | st |  8  |
Fred | ot |  2  |
Fred | dt |  3  |
Jane | st |  8  |
Jane | ot |  1  |
Samm | st |  8  |
Samm | dt |  6  |
Alex | st |  8  |
```

How can I modify the query to get the above desired output?

Comment: Do you want to include names in the result where all value columns are `0` - with one row holding NULL in `t` and `val`?

Comment: So do you have your answer?

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT
  times.name, x.t, x.val
FROM
  times cross join lateral (values('st',st),('ot',ot),('dt',dt)) as x(t,val)
WHERE
  x.val <> 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

The core problem is the **reverse of a pivot / crosstab** operation. Sometimes called **"unpivot"**.

Basically, [Abelisto's query](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45201903/939860) is the way to go in Postgres 9.3 or later. Related:

- [SELECT DISTINCT on multiple columns](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/102702/3684)

You *may* want to use `LEFT JOIN LATERAL ... ON u.val <> 0` to include names without valid values in the result (and shorten the syntax a bit).

- [What is the difference between LATERAL JOIN and a subquery in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28550679/what-is-the-difference-between-lateral-and-a-subquery-in-postgresql/28557803#28557803)

If you have more than a few value columns (or varying lists of columns) you may want to use a function to build and execute the query automatically:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_unpivot_columns(VARIADIC _cols text[])
  RETURNS TABLE(name text, t text, val int)
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
BEGIN
   RETURN QUERY EXECUTE (
   SELECT
     'SELECT t.name, u.t, u.val
      FROM   times t
      LEFT   JOIN LATERAL (VALUES '
          || string_agg(format('(%L, t.%I)', c, c), ', ')
          || ') u(t, val) ON (u.val <> 0)'
   FROM   unnest(_cols) c
   );
END
$func$;
```

Call:

```
SELECT * FROM f_unpivot_times_columns(VARIADIC '{st, ot, dt}');
```

Or:

```
SELECT * FROM f_unpivot_columns('ot', 'dt');
```

Columns names are provided as string literals and must be in correct (case-sensitive!) spelling with no extra double-quotes. See:

- [Are PostgreSQL column names case-sensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20878932/are-postgresql-column-names-case-sensitive/20880247#20880247)

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=7d3803156d210ca0dc670cc56be26ba7)*

Related with more examples and explanation:

- [How to unpivot a table in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25625342/how-to-unpivot-a-table-in-postgresql/25627588#25627588)

Answer (score 0):

One way:

```
with times(name , st , ot , dt) as(
select 'Fred',8  , 2  , 3  union all
select 'Jane',8  , 1  , 0  union all
select 'Samm',8  , 0  , 6  union all
select 'Alex',8  , 0  , 0  
)

select name, key as t, value::int  from 
(
    select name, json_build_object('st' ,st , 'ot',ot, 'dt',dt) as j
    from times
) t
join lateral json_each_text(j)
on true
where value <> '0'
-- order by name, case when key = 'st' then 0 when key = 'ot' then 1 when key = 'dt' then 2 end
```

Comment: Was about to suggest LATERAL example also, but you got first :) Still, you do not need to build any json object and parse it. Simple `.. FROM times t, LATERAL ( VALUES ('st', t.st), ('ot', t.ot), ('dt', t.dt) ) c(t, val)` does the trick, because you can reference to `times` table in LATERAL.

Comment: @ KristoMägi - Yeah, you're right. Just first thing appeared in my brain was using json, probably not most optimal way

Comment: Another comment: when building static data-set with CTE then you do not need to `SELECT .. UNION ALL`, using VALUES is enough like that: `...AS ( VALUES ( 'Fred', 8, 2, 3 ), ( 'Jane', 8, 1, 0 ), ( 'Samm', 8, 0, 6 ), ( 'Alex', 8, 0, 0 ) )..` :)