# Postgres: convert single row to multiple rows (unpivot)

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, data-manipulation, unpivot

I have a table:

```
Table_Name: price_list
---------------------------------------------------
| id | price_type_a | price_type_b | price_type_c |
---------------------------------------------------
| 1  |    1234      |     5678     |     9012     |
| 2  |    3456      |     7890     |     1234     |
| 3  |    5678      |     9012     |     3456     |
---------------------------------------------------
```

I need a select query in Postgres which gives result like this:

```
---------------------------
| id | price_type | price |
---------------------------
| 1  |  type_a    | 1234  |
| 1  |  type_b    | 5678  |
| 1  |  type_c    | 9012  |
| 2  |  type_a    | 3456  |
| 2  |  type_b    | 7890  |
| 2  |  type_c    | 1234  |
...
```

Any help with links to similar examples greatly appreciated.

Comment: just `select id,'a', a union select id,'b'b and so on`?..

Comment: Thanks ! that works great.. will it be optimal for large amounts of data?

Comment: nothing smarter comes ATM anyway :)

Comment: Thats alright. I was thinking Is there a way to do it via pivot or unpivot? because I have a huge amount of data in this table, pivot would be more optimal that way instead of having multiple unions right?

Comment: You would have to look into the [`tablefunc`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tablefunc.html), and in particular at the `crosstab` function.

Comment: could you give an example snippet for how we can use `crosstab` for this case?

Comment: @s.m.: Crosstab is related, but for "pivoting" (see basics here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11751905/939860). This task is the reverse operation: "unpivoting".

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter & OP: apologies, I got it completely backwards.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A single `SELECT` with a `LATERAL` join to a `VALUES` expression does the job of "un-pivoting" columns to separate rows:

```sql
SELECT p.id, v.*
FROM   price_list p
CROSS  JOIN LATERAL (
   VALUES
      ('type_a', p.price_type_a)
    , ('type_b', p.price_type_b)
    , ('type_c', p.price_type_c)
   ) v (price_type, price);
```

Related:

- [Convert one row into multiple rows with fewer columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45201170/convert-one-row-into-multiple-rows-with-fewer-columns/45204205#45204205)
- [SELECT DISTINCT on multiple columns](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/102702/3684)

Comment: What if I have a list of 50 columns like this with multiple values. Is there a better way?

Comment: @sanchitkhanna26: This works for any number of columns. I suggest you start a *new question* with the details of your use case, and of your objective. (What's "better"? Faster? Safer? Shorter? ...)

Answer (score 0):

try smth like:

```
select id, 'type_a',type_a  from price_list
union all
select id, 'type_b',type_b  from price_list
union all
select id, 'type_c',type_c  from price_list
;
```

**update**
as a_horse_with_no_name suggests, union is way to select `DISTINCT` values, for here would be `UNION ALL` prefered - just in case (I don't know if id is UNIQUE)

Of course if it is UK - there will be no difference