# Transpose single row with multiple columns into multiple rows of two columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, transpose, crosstab, unpivot

I have a `SELECT` query that works perfectly fine and it returns a single row with multiple named columns:

```
| registered | downloaded | subscribed | requested_invoice | paid |
|------------|------------|------------|-------------------|------|
| 9000       | 7000       | 5000       | 4000              | 3000 |
```

But I need to transpose this result to a new table that looks like this:

```
| type              | value |
|-------------------|-------|
| registered        | 9000  |
| downloaded        | 7000  |
| subscribed        | 5000  |
| requested_invoice | 4000  |
| paid              | 3000  |
```

I have the additional module `tablefunc` enabled at PostgreSQL but I can't get  the `crosstab()` function to work for this. What can I do?

Comment: You could use `UNION ALL`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the ***reverse*** operation of what `crosstab()` does. Some call it "unpivot". A `LATERAL` join to a `VALUES` expression should be the most elegant way:

```sql
SELECT l.*
FROM   tbl     --  or replace the table with your subquery
CROSS  JOIN LATERAL (
   VALUES
  ('registered'       , registered)
, ('downloaded'       , downloaded)
, ('subscribed'       , subscribed)
, ('requested_invoice', requested_invoice)
, ('paid'             , paid)
   ) l(type, value)
WHERE  id = 1;  --  or whatever
```

You may need to cast some or all columns to arrive at a common data type. Like:

```sql
...
   VALUES
  ('registered'       , registered::text)
, ('downloaded'       , downloaded::text)
, ...
```

Related:

- [Postgres: convert single row to multiple rows (unpivot)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47077068/postgres-convert-single-row-to-multiple-rows-unpivot/47077708#47077708)

For the *reverse* operation - "pivot" or "cross-tabulation":

- [PostgreSQL Crosstab Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002499/postgresql-crosstab-query/11751905#11751905)