# Query to return sum for multiple columns as separate rows

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot, aggregate, apache-superset

I'm trying to generate the following output:

| type | totals |
| --- | --- |
| CostA | 1500 |
| CostB | 200 |
| CostC | 300 |

From a table with this structure:

```
CostA
CostB
CostC
name
date
-- more columns ...
```

The table has more columns but I want the sum for only 3 of them.

I need this structure specifically because superset expects a structure like this to generate some charts.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

> as you can see, the table has more columns but I want the sum of only
> 3 columns.

You can do it using `union all` :

```
SELECT 'CostA' AS type, SUM(CostA) AS totals FROM table_name
UNION ALL
SELECT 'CostB' AS type, SUM(CostB) AS totals FROM table_name
UNION ALL
SELECT 'CostC' AS type, SUM(CostC) AS totals FROM table_name;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using `unnest()` as follows :

```
with cte as (
  select sum(CostA) as CostA, sum(CostB) as CostB, sum(CostC) as CostC
  from mytable
)
SELECT
   unnest(array['CostA', 'CostB', 'CostC']) AS type,
   unnest(array[CostA, CostB, CostC]) AS total
FROM cte
ORDER BY total
```

Answer (score 1):

If the source table is big, it pays to compute all sums in a **single `SELECT`** (close to 1/3 the cost), and then pivot results - with a `VALUES` expression in a `LATERAL` join:

```sql
SELECT pivot.*
FROM  (
   SELECT sum(CostA) AS a
        , sum(CostB) AS b
        , sum(CostC) AS c
   FROM   tbl
   ) sub
CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
   VALUES
     ('CostA', a)
   , ('CostB', b)
   , ('CostC', c)
   ) pivot(type, total);
```

See:

- [Transpose single row with multiple columns into multiple rows of two columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56877924/transpose-single-row-with-multiple-columns-into-multiple-rows-of-two-columns/56878197#56878197)

Aside: avoid CaMeL-case identifiers in Postgres if at all possible. See:

- [Are PostgreSQL column names case-sensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20878932/are-postgresql-column-names-case-sensitive/20880247#20880247)