# Optimize query for columns with distinct values per ID

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-performance

Got this question for a while and wondering if there is any faster query.

I have a table with multiple entries per ID, and would like to list all columns with different values for the same ID.

| ID | Brand | Type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Honda | Coupe |
| 1 | Jeep | SUV |
| 2 | Ford | Sedan |
| 2 | Ford | Crossover |

Example for above table:
Rows with `ID = 1` have different `Brand` and `Type` values, so I want one result row for each column.
For `ID = 2` there is only one brand, but multiple types, so only one result row for type.

The desired result would be like this.

| ID | Difference |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Brand |
| 1 | Type |
| 2 | Type |

I solved it with below query checking each column with one `SELECT` statement and then `UNION` it all:

```
SELECT ID, 'Brand' AS Discrepancy
FROM table
GROUP BY ID
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Brand) > 1

UNION 

SELECT ID,'Type' AS Discrepancy
FROM table
GROUP BY ID
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Type) > 1;
```

Is there any faster query or optimization?

Comment: Your current query is already pretty optimal.

Comment: To be clear, the query is *not* optimal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your query is good for **few** rows per ID (except for <strike>`UNION`</strike> where it should be `UNION ALL`).
This one is better (improved with a hint from [Charlieface](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14868997/charlieface)):

```sql
SELECT t.id, c.difference
FROM  (
   SELECT id
        , min(brand) <> max(brand) AS b_diff
        , min(type)  <> max(type)  AS t_diff
   FROM   tbl
   GROUP  BY id
   ) t
JOIN   LATERAL (
   VALUES
     ('Brand', t.b_diff)
   , ('Type' , t.t_diff)
   ) c(difference, diff) ON c.diff
ORDER  BY 1, 2;  -- optional
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/x8KFrHnX)

A *single* sequential scan should bring the cost down by almost half.
Plus, avoiding the expensive `count(DISTINCT ...)` should help some more.
Test with `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`. See:

- [Same result without using UNION ALL on repeating SELECT statements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78010250/same-result-without-using-union-all-on-repeating-select-statements/78011352#78011352)

Note that null values are ignored by either query.

**If** there are **many** rows per ID (and an index on each of the tested columns), there are (much) faster options.
If so, and it matters, start a new question providing info for [postgresql-performance](/questions/tagged/postgresql-performance) questions as [instructed in the tag description](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/postgresql-performance/info). Postgres version, exact table definition, test case. Most importantly, rough stats about data distribution. And post a comment here to link to the follow-up.

Comment: `MIN(x) <> MAX(x)` is probably much faster than doing multiple `COUNT(DISTINCT`

Comment: Yes, min + max is certainly cheaper, yet. The major factor is one sequential (or index) scan instead of multiple, though. I added a variant as per your suggestion. If columns of interest have many entries per ID, and an index, there are (much) faster ways, yet ... (reposted to clarify few vs. many )

Comment: I don't have time to explore this, as postgresql isn't in my wheelhouse, but I was in the process of suggesting the use of a window function OVER partition by ID in combination with JOIN lateral to derive a change count for each field independently.  I'd be curious to see what you think of the idea.

Comment: @gview: Since we `GROUP BY id`, I don't see what a window function could buy at this point ...

Comment: It would be an alternative to group by id, and with the ability to compare each row within the window with the previous one, you could just create a value if there was a difference.  Likely a similar final result, with similar performance I'm guessing.

Comment: @gview: We basically want 1 aggregated row per group. Aggregate functions are the way to go. I don't think similar performance is possible with window functions in this case. I would be very interested if you could prove me wrong. But I won't hold my breath. ;)

Comment: Appreciate your response @ErwinBrandstetter

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Really appreciate!! Look likes still lots of things I need to learn! Appreciate your super useful suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`to_json()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#id-1.5.8.22.8.9.2.2.1.1.2.1) to avoid hardcoding field names: it fetches your column names to use them as keys in JSON. Then you can unpivot that with [`json_each_text()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#id-1.5.8.22.8.13.2.2.5.1.2.1), spitting them back out with their corresponding values, to be checked by `count(distinct v)`. [Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/qCiHqs9D):

```sql
select id, column_name as "Difference"
from test, json_each_text(to_json(test)) as a(column_name, v)
group by id, column_name
having min(v) <> max(v);
```

It also does the job in a single pass and you can keep [@Charlieface's trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78031456/optimize-query-for-columns-with-distinct-values-per-id#comment137565325_78031601) with `min<>max` alternative to counting. Keep in mind that regardless of the number of columns, it only wins the *"brevity"* and *"it's dynamic"* participation awards, getting [easily outperformed](https://dbfiddle.uk/iOPgufOD) by the variant that doesn't multiply the set by unpivoting.

Choice boils down to speed at the cost of maintenance effort (column alteration needs to be cascaded wherever they are hardcoded), or set-it-and-forget-it convenience if you can afford the price in performance.