# Optimize query for columns with distinct values incl. NULL

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-performance

| ID | Amount | Brand |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | NULL |
| 1 | 20 | NULL |
| 2 | 30 | Mazada |
| 2 | NULL | BMW |
| 3 | 40 | NULL |
| 3 | 40 | KIA |
| 4 | NULL | Honda |
| 4 | NULL | Honda |

Above is the original table, and my goal is to find any difference within the same ID for each column.

For every ID group, if there is any difference in a value column, return a new row with the column name.

The outcome should be like this:

| ID | Difference |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Amount |
| 2 | Amount |
| 2 | Brand |
| 3 | Brand |

My code for PostgreSQL:

```
SELECT
    ID,
    'Amount' AS Difference
FROM
    table
GROUP BY
    ID
HAVING
    COUNT(DISTINCT amount) > 1
    OR (COUNT(amount) != COUNT(*) AND COUNT(DISTINCT amount) > 0)

UNION ALL 

SELECT
    ID,
    'Brand' AS Difference
FROM
    table
GROUP BY
    ID
HAVING
    COUNT(DISTINCT brand) > 1
    OR (COUNT(brand) != COUNT(*) AND COUNT(DISTINCT brand) > 0)
```

Be careful that there is NULL value in the record, so that the aggregation function would not count the NULL value. The NULL vs NULL view it as same, but NULL vs any value view it as difference.

Is there any better or faster query for this solution? Like lateral join or window function?

Comment: Is it guaranteed that there will be exactly two rows per group? Can it be 1? Or 3?

Comment: You ask for a faster query. So disclose your exact table definition, cardinalities and Postgres version. Consider instructions for [\[postgresql-performance\]](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/postgresql-performance/info) questions:

Comment: Vote to reopen: this thread builds on top of [the old one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78031456/optimize-query-for-columns-with-distinct-values-per-id), adding the *`null`* handling context - it's clearly based on the remark in the accepted answer there and I think opening a new, separate thread to address that, was a good move. That's in contrast to continually mutating the old one again and again, through the addition of criteria based on remarks raised throughout the discussion, especially in answers. If anything, I'd close the old one, as this one's now more valuable.

Answer (score 2):

A single pass over the table should be quite a bit faster:

```sql
SELECT id, col
FROM  (
   SELECT id
        , min(amount) <> max(amount) AS a_diff, bool_or(true) FILTER (WHERE amount IS NULL) AS a_null
        , min(brand)  <> max(brand)  AS b_diff, bool_or(true) FILTER (WHERE brand  IS NULL) AS b_null
   FROM   tbl
   GROUP  BY id
   ) t
JOIN   LATERAL (
   VALUES
     ('Amount', a_diff, a_null)
   , ('Brand' , b_diff, b_null)
   ) x(col, diff, has_null) ON (diff OR NOT diff AND has_null)
ORDER  BY id, col
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Y_UoDAGS)

Plus, `count(DISTINCT ...)` is notoriously expensive. And we don't actually need that count. We just need to know if the min value differs from the max (or does not, but there is also at least one `NULL`).

Very similar case with more explanation:

- [Optimize query for columns with distinct values per ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78031456/optimize-query-for-columns-with-distinct-values-per-id/78031601#78031601)

Looks like [you have seen that one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78031456/optimize-query-for-columns-with-distinct-values-per-id/78031601#comment137576217_78031601), but not yet applied to your case.
Like I mentioned over there: there are faster ways for *many* rows per group ...