# Postgres: Convert single rows from multiple tables into multiple rows in a single table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have data scattered across multiple tables and rows that I'd like to aggregate into a more usable format for my use case. The problem boils down to something like this...

If I have two tables like this:

```
product_id  title_id  description_id
1           123       234 
2           345       456
3           567       678
```

```
product_id  additional_info_id
1           789
1           890
2           901
```

How would I construct a query to return data like this?

```
product_id  content_id  content_type
1           123         title 
1           234         description
1           789         additional_info
1           890         additional_info
2           345         title
2           456         description
2           901         additional_info
3           567         title
3           678         Description
```

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47077068/postgres-convert-single-row-to-multiple-rows-unpivot) post and I can construct a query like this

```
select
    p.product_id,
    p_content.*
from
    product p,
    lateral (values
        (p.title_id, 'title'),
        (p.description_id, 'description')
    ) p_content (content_id, content_type)
;
```

to get the data from the `product` table in the format I need, but I can't figure out how to incorporate the data from the `additional_info` table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `union all`:

```
select p.product_id, v.content_id, v.content_type
from product p cross join lateral
     (values (p.title_id, 'title'),
             (p.description_id, 'description')
     ) v(content_id, content_type)
union all
select product_id, additional_info_id, 'additional_info'
from additional_info ai;
```