# Get certain rows, plus rows before and after

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions, gaps-and-islands

Let's say I have the following data set:

| ID | Identifier | Admission_Date | Release_Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 234 | 2 | 5/1/22 | 5/5/22 |
| 234 | 1 | 4/25/22 | 4/30/22 |
| 234 | 2 | 4/20/22 | 4/24/22 |
| 234 | 2 | 4/15/22 | 4/18/22 |
| 789 | 1 | 7/15/22 | 7/19/22 |
| 789 | 2 | 7/8/22 | 7/14/22 |
| 789 | 2 | 7/1/22 | 7/5/22 |
| 321 | 2 | 6/1/21 | 6/3/21 |
| 321 | 2 | 5/27/21 | 5/31/21 |
| 321 | 1 | 5/20/21 | 5/26/21 |
| 321 | 2 | 5/15/21 | 5/19/21 |
| 321 | 2 | 5/6/21 | 5/10/21 |

I want all rows with `identifier=1`. I also want rows that are either directly below or above rows with `Identifier=1` - sorted by most recent to least recent.

There is always a row below rows with `identifier=1`. There may or may not be a row above. If there is no row with `identifier=1` for an `ID`, then it will not be brought in with a prior step.

The resulting data set should be as follows:

| ID | Identifier | Admission Date | Release Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 234 | 2 | 5/1/22 | 5/5/22 |
| 234 | 1 | 4/25/22 | 4/30/22 |
| 234 | 2 | 4/20/22 | 4/24/22 |
| 789 | 1 | 7/15/22 | 7/19/22 |
| 789 | 2 | 7/8/22 | 7/14/22 |
| 321 | 2 | 5/27/21 | 5/31/21 |
| 321 | 1 | 5/20/21 | 5/26/21 |
| 321 | 2 | 5/15/21 | 5/19/21 |

I am using DBeaver, which runs PostgreSQL.

Comment: A fiddle would be nice ([random example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_15&fiddle=aa472404627970e744261c4e17239152)) - with actual `CREATE TABLE` statements showing data types and constraints. And your version of Postgres.

Comment: Have you checked out the LEAD and the LAG window functions?  What do you mean by "above" and "below"?  In your example ID=234 has two rows with Identifier=2 - why/how do you consider the 4/20 one to be included over the 4/15?  Is there an ORDER BY Admission_Date DESC in your query?

Comment: So do you have your answer?

Comment: yes............

Answer (score 0):

I admittedly don't know Postgres well so the following could possibly be optimised, however using a combination of *lag* and *lead* to obtain the previous and next dates (assuming Admission_date is the one to order by) you could try

```
with d as (
  select *, 
    case when identifier = 1 then Lag(admission_date) over(partition by id order by Admission_Date desc) end pd, 
    case when identifier = 1 then Lead(admission_date) over(partition by id order by Admission_Date desc) end nd
  from t
)
select id, Identifier, Admission_Date, Release_Date
from d
where identifier = 1
or exists (
  select * from d d2 
  where d2.id = d.id
    and (d.Admission_Date = pd or d.admission_date = nd)
)
order by Id, Admission_Date desc;
```

Comment: Amazing! I have some more QA to do, but this seems to be doing what I want

Answer (score 0):

One way:

```sql
SELECT (x.my_row).*  -- decompose fields from row type
FROM  (
   SELECT identifier
        , lag(t)  OVER w AS t0  -- take whole row
        , t              AS t1
        , lead(t) OVER w AS t2
   FROM   tbl t
   WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY admission_date)
   ) sub
CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
   VALUES (t0), (t1), (t2)  -- pivot
    ) x(my_row)
WHERE  sub.identifier = 1
AND    (x.my_row).id IS NOT NULL;  -- exclude rows with NULL ( = missing row)
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_15&fiddle=0e11e415ac31483d7cd2b46d91ba89bd)*

The query is designed to only make a single pass over the table.
Uses some advanced SQL / Postgres features.

About `LATERAL`:

- [What is the difference between a LATERAL JOIN and a subquery in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28550679/what-is-the-difference-between-lateral-join-and-a-subquery-in-postgresql/28557803#28557803)

About the `VALUES` expression:

- [Postgres: convert single row to multiple rows (unpivot)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47077068/postgres-convert-single-row-to-multiple-rows-unpivot/47077708#47077708)

[The manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#FIELD-SELECTION) about extracting fields from a composite type.

If there are *many* rows per `id`, other solutions will be (much) faster - with proper index support. You did not specify ...