# Custom column in Postgres based on columns the data came from

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to aggregate data in a concise way from multiple tables. I'm not very experienced with Postgres or SQL, however, so I was hoping I could get some help from here!

The situation is as follows: I have three columns containing text, from two different tables. Let's call them table A and B. I want to search A.text1, A.text2 and B.text3 for the wildcard '%postgres%'. I want the result to return all the instances containing that wildcard to me.

What I would like is a result that looks something like this:

| Type | Text |
| --- | --- |
| text1 | ... postgres ... |
| text2 | ... postgres ... |
| text3 | ... postgres ... |

My question is: is this feasible, and if it is feasible, can you point me in the right direction to achieve such a result?

The current solution I have created for this is:

```sql
select a.text1, a.text2, b.text3
from a
inner join b
on a.id = b.aId
where a.text1 like '%postgres%'
or a.text2 like '%postgres%'
or b.text3 like '%postgres%'
```

This works, but the result is kind of ugly. There are a lot of cells that contain '[null]' and I don't really like that. It looks like this:

| a.text1 | a.text2 | b.text3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| null | ... postgres ... | null |
| ... postgres ... | ... postgres ... | null |
| null | null | ... postgres ... |

Update: I have solved the problem! The sql I ended up with is:

```sql
select * from
(select 'text1' as type, text1 as text from a
union all
select 'text2' as type, text2 as text from a
union all
select 'text3' as type, text3 as text from b) as result
where result.text like '%postgres%'
```

Comment: Perhaps UNION ALL should be considered?

Comment: @jarlh Thank you for the comment. Using unions, I have solved the problem!

Comment: Well-formulated question and you even went through lengths of styling the tables! Lovely work and welcome!

Comment: I agree, well done for a first question! Please remember to always disclose your version of Postgres (`SELECT version();` helps.) And if performance matters, consider https://stackoverflow.com/tags/postgresql-performance/info

Answer (score 1):

Your query with `UNION ALL` basically answers the question. I would suggest some optimization:

```sql
SELECT t.*
FROM   a
JOIN   LATERAL (
   VALUES
     ('text1', text1)
   , ('text2', text2)
   ) t (type, "text") ON "text" ~ 'postgres'

UNION ALL
SELECT 'text3', text3
FROM   b
WHERE  b.text3 ~ 'postgres';
```

Table `a` is only scanned once instead of twice this way, which is about half the cost. And all rows are filtered early - also cheaper.

About `LATERAL ( ... VALUES ...)`:

- [Postgres: convert single row to multiple rows (unpivot)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47077068/postgres-convert-single-row-to-multiple-rows-unpivot/47077708#47077708)

`"text" ~ 'postgres'` is equivalent to `"text" LIKE '%postgres%'`. Only special characters in the search string might make a difference. See:

- [Escape function for regular expression or LIKE patterns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5144036/escape-function-for-regular-expression-or-like-patterns/45741630#45741630)

If tables are big, trigram indexes on the text columns help a lot. See:

- [PostgreSQL LIKE query performance variations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566717/postgresql-like-query-performance-variations/13452528#13452528)

I double-quoted the identifier `"text"` to avoid collisions with the basic type name `text`. Rather avoid basic type names as identifier altogether.

Comment: Very informative, thanks for the extensive answer! A lateral join on the two fields is a great optimization, and I'll make sure to learn what I can from the links you provided.