# Query for crosstab view

Tags: sql, postgresql, crosstab, unpivot

I have a table in PostgreSQL like below:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------
Item1 | Item2 | Item3 | Item4 |Value1| Value2| Value3| Value4|
--------------------------------------------------------------
```

I want a query which will show this table like below:

```
ItemHead| ValueHead
---------------
Item1 | Value1|
---------------
Item2 | Value2| 
----------------
Item3 | Value3| 
----------------
Item4 | Value4|
---------------
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a *single* `SELECT` with a `LATERAL` join to a `VALUES` expression. That's shorter and faster than multiple `SELECT` statements:

```sql
SELECT v.*
FROM   tbl, LATERAL (
   VALUES
      (item1, value1)
    , (item2, value2)  -- data types must be compatible
    , (item3, value3)
    , (item4, value4)
   ) v ("ItemHead", "ValueHead");  -- your desired column names
```

Related:

- [Convert one row into multiple rows with fewer columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45201170/convert-one-row-into-multiple-rows-with-fewer-columns/45204205#45204205)
- [SELECT DISTINCT on multiple columns](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/102702/3684)
- [Postgres: convert single row to multiple rows (unpivot)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47077068/postgres-convert-single-row-to-multiple-rows/47077708#47077708)

Note: You added the tag [crosstab](/questions/tagged/crosstab). But the Postgres function `crosstab()` from the additional [`tablefunc` module](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tablefunc.html) is used for *pivoting*, while this task is the opposite, sometimes referred to as *unpivoting*. Related:

- [PostgreSQL Crosstab Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002499/postgresql-crosstab-query/11751905#11751905)

Comment: really nice one, I've never seen such notation

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `UNION ALL`

```
SELECT item1, value1 FROM your_tab
UNION ALL
SELECT item2, value2 FROM your_tab
UNION ALL
SELECT item3, value3 FROM your_tab
UNION ALL
SELECT item4, value4 FROM your_tab
```