# Sort events by highest occurrence by year

Tags: sql, postgresql, sorting

I am trying to find how many events occur by year. Currently I have this query, that basically counts when an event has visitors:

```
SELECT 
count(visitors_y_2016) as y_16,
count(visitors_y_2017) as y_17,
count(visitors_y_2018) as y_18,
count(visitors_y_2019) as y_19, 
count(visitors_y_2020) as y_20
FROM event
;
```

---

```
y16  y17  y18  y19  y20 
23   25   26   27   19
```

But what I am looking for is an order by the year with more events:

```
Y19 27
Y18 26
y17 25
y16 23
y20 19
```

Any idea how to accomplish that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your table design looks quite strange, as such information should be in rows and not columns.

But you can `UNION` all results and then sort them

> ```
> CREATE TABLE event (visitors_y_2016 int,visitors_y_2017 int,visitors_y_2018 int,visitors_y_2019 i
> ```

> ```
> (SELECT 
> 'y_16' ,count(visitors_y_2016) as cnt
> FROM event
> UNION ALL
> SELECT 
> 'y_17',count(visitors_y_2017)
> FROM event
> UNION ALL
> SELECT 
> 'y_18',
> count(visitors_y_2018) 
> FROM event
> UNION ALL
> SELECT 
> 'y_19',
> count(visitors_y_2019) 
> FROM event
> UNION ALL
> SELECT 
> 'y_20',
> count(visitors_y_2020) 
> FROM event)
> ORDER BY cnt
> ;
> ```

> ```
> ?column? | cnt
> :------- | --:
> y_16     |   0
> y_17     |   0
> y_18     |   0
> y_19     |   0
> y_20     |   0
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=80b458bca99591a3ffc0a2ad8f0e759c)*

Comment: well, three structure of this external data is just-> line: event name, column: year attendance.

Comment: Then use the selects to generate your count and union them as shown,cte is of course also a possibilty

Answer (score 1):

You can "unpivot" with a `VALUES` expression in a `LATERAL` subquery:

```sql
SELECT t.*
FROM  (
   SELECT count(visitors_y_2016) AS y16
        , count(visitors_y_2017) AS y17
        , count(visitors_y_2018) AS y18
        , count(visitors_y_2019) AS y19 
        , count(visitors_y_2020) AS y20
   FROM   event
   ) e, LATERAL (
   VALUES
     (16, e.y16)
   , (17, e.y17)
   , (18, e.y18)
   , (19, e.y19)
   , (20, e.y20)
   ) t(year, count)
ORDER  BY count DESC;  -- your desired sort order
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=f40e145b4bf01926d1fe8eb93733733a)*

Since this only needs a **single scan** over the table, it's many times faster than aggregating ever output value separately.

Each line in the `VALUES` expression forms a row with two columns: `year` (number defaults to `integer`) and `count` (type of referenced column).

See:

- [Query for crosstab view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47133450/query-for-crosstab-view/47138903#47138903)
- [SELECT DISTINCT on multiple columns](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/102702/3684)

About `LATERAL` subqueries:

- [What is the difference between LATERAL JOIN and a subquery in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28550679/what-is-the-difference-between-lateral-join-and-a-subquery-in-postgresql/28557803#28557803)

But your table design raises questions. Typically you'd have a single date or timestamp column `visitors` instead of `visitors_y_2016`, `visitors_y_2017` etc. - and a simpler query based on that ...

Comment: @shawnt00: Not sure I understand your question. The lateral subquery can reference columns from all table expressions to the left in the same `FROM` clause. I clarified a bit. The added links should explain some more.

Comment: Sorry I just misread and overlooked the whole subquery/derived table entirely. I thought you were referring to columns that didn't exist yet.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think you need a select on each year. I don't exactly know your table, but there should be a better wayu to organize your data. Also, SORT BY should be your friend if you wanna sort data. You just gotta have a single SELECT to use it like for example:

```
SORT BY
VISITOR_COUNT
```

Comment: You probably mean `ORDER BY`. But that still wouldn't address the question.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).